# How to register on gcm to get the registration id from gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use GCM in my project I read about the GCM i understood the working of it but when i am not unable to understand how we do code to get the registration id form GCM can you give me full code to get the registration id from GCM please don't say that do google.
please give me code how can i register on GCM and how can I get registration id from GCM.

Comment: Have a look at the sample https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Comment: *please give me code how can i register on GCM and how can I get registration id from GCM*, really?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 meh, just for that line i gave him the *full code* expecting him not to get it working...

Comment: @Shark: You shouldn't have. Why? Asking for code is **off-topic** and this like spoon feeding which makes new developers not to read anything and try on their own.

Comment: @Shark please reply me in your answer

Comment: @Rohit5k2 sometimes I give them the code to get a laugh out of it, and sometimes I do not because I see that they are very close to figuring it out on themselves. This guy falls in neither of these two cathegories, so I see no harm done. If, however, there was some harm done - please report my answer and flag a moderator.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 sorry sir but i am trying for two-three days i am not getting result as i want so i am asking in last

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
private void registerInBackground() {

    gcmRegistrationInProcces = true;

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (Application.gcm == null) {
                    Application.gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                }
                GCM_REGISTRATION_ID = Application.gcm.register(GCM_SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + GCM_REGISTRATION_ID;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(getApplicationContext(), GCM_REGISTRATION_ID);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }

            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            gcmRegistrationInProcces = false;

            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) 
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registered with REG_ID:\n"+GCM_REGISTRATION_ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: i have a register page with three fields on register i go in another activity now i want to use GCM and i read about sender id, project id and API key how and where i can use these thing

Comment: And also tell me these three things are necessary?

Comment: Yes they are. You really should read [the article on google](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) about it. Also, thanks for accepting the answer when you get it working.

Comment: yes sure i will read once again and i will accept answer if it will work for me

Comment: The code is production-ready as I know it works... do try to get it working for you as well. Best wishes.